# Setter method for an object using a special logic

Tags: java

I have a method that received a list of CoordinateBE : **setExits(..)**

I want to update the existing coordinates list with a new coordinate only if there is no coordinate in the current list that has the same latitude and longitude.

**Example**:

List: [Coordinate: lat:23, long:24, Coordinate: lat:34, long:24]

I am trying to add a new Coordinate: Coordinate: lat:23, long: 24 ---> this one I cannot add it because already exists in the list.

My implementation is working, but I was wondering if I can improve it, for example through lambda expressions, etc. Do you have any ideas?

// setter

```
  public void setExits(final List<CoordinateBE> exits) {
            if (getExits().isEmpty()) {
                this.exits = exits;
            } else {
                if (!existenceOfCoordinates(getExits(), exits)) {
                    final List<CoordinateBE> result = new ArrayList<>();
                    result.addAll(getExits());
                    result.addAll(exits);
                    this.exits = result;
                }
            }
        }
```

//getter

```
  public List<CoordinateBE> getExits() {
     return exits;
  }
```

// existenceOfCoordinates

```
 private boolean existenceOfCoordinates(final List<CoordinateBE> existingCoordinates, final List<CoordinateBE> currentCoordinates) {
    for (final CoordinateBE existingCoordinate : existingCoordinates) {
        for (final CoordinateBE currCoordinateBE : currentCoordinates) {
            if (compareCoordinates(existingCoordinate, currCoordinateBE)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
 }
```

// compareCoordinates

```
 private boolean compareCoordinates(final CoordinateBE existingCoordinate, final CoordinateBE newCoordinate) {
        return existingCoordinate.getLatitude().equals(newCoordinate.getLatitude())
                && existingCoordinate.getLongitude().equals(newCoordinate.getLongitude());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Getters and setters for collections can be dangerous if not implemented correctly**

First of all, getters exist for external code to access the internal fields in your class. The code in your class should not rely on them to access it's own internal data structures. Always refer to the field directly with `this.exits` instead of using `getExits()`.

Because you use the `getExits()` method from within the class you allow others to break your implementation by overloading the `getExits()` method and returning a manipulated list. In general, if your algorithm relies on specific functionality of it's own `public` methods, those methods should be made `final`.

Because the `getExits()` method returns the object reference directly, it exposes it's internal data structure for other classes to modify and accidentally break. Some other class may now call your `getExits()` method and pass the list to some other completely unrelated code that deletes or add entries to it. Now your object no longer contains the coordinates you intended. That kind of bugs can be a bit hard to trace. Getters that expose internal data structures should be written to use unmodifiable lists instead:

```
public List<CoordinateBE> getExits() {
   return Collections.unmodifiableList(exits);
}
```

This is still not a 100% fool proof method, because the underlyig `exits` list is still shared by your class and the caller. While the caller can not modify the list, the list can still be modified by your class without the knowledge of the caller, which may cause surprising bugs in the caller. To prevent that you need to create a copy of the list, but that comes with a performance penalty if your lists are large or the getter is called repeatedly.

Same applies to your setter as you're directly storing the incoming list reference to the internal field. Now you're again sharing the same list entity in two different parts of code. The setter should always copy the entries to an internal list.

```
this.exits = new ArrayList<>(exits);
```

**Setters have a specific and well defined functionality**

The intended purpose of setter methods is to discard whatever existing value the object had in the specific field and replace it with the provided value. Your setter method breaks this contract as it adds values to the `exits`-list instead. Thus the setter should be named something else, such as `addExits(...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you recreate `this.exits` every time you add new items? This:

```java
                    final List<CoordinateBE> result = new ArrayList<>();
                    result.addAll(getExits());
                    result.addAll(exits);
                    this.exits = result;
```

could be simplified to

```java
                    this.exits.addAll(exits);
```

---

If coordinates are always meaningfully equal based on latitude + longitude, you may want to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` so that so you can better leverage built-in methods. With an overrided `equals()`, you would not need `compareCoordinates`, and `existenceOfCoordinates` could be replaced with collection methods.

For example:

```java
private boolean existenceOfCoordinates2(List<CoordinateBE> a, List<CoordinateBE> b) {
  return b.stream().anyMatch(a::contains);
}
```

---

With the above simplifications, (I'll skip the `equals()` override in case you actually don't want that), it's distilled down to:

```java
public void setExits(final List<CoordinateBE> exits) {
  if (!getExits().isEmpty()) {
    // Check that no new exits are already in the list
    for (CoordinateBE exit : getExits()) {
      if (exits.stream().anyMatch(x -> compareCoordinates(x, c))) {
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  this.exits.addAll(exits);
}


// If CoordinateBE overrides equals(), you could also do:

public void setExits(final List<CoordinateBE> exits) {
  // In this case, I'm not checking whether this.exits is empty, because
  // we're streaming the new exits as opposed to the current, and that stream
  // will just be empty if the new exits are empty.
  if (exits.stream().anyMatch(this.exits::contains)) {
    return;
  }
  this.exits.addAll(exits);
}
```

---

Finally, I am assuming that order is important here, which is why you're using a List as opposed to a Set. Even so, if you're okay with overriding `equals()` and if duplicates are not allowed, using a `LinkedHashSet` for `this.exits` would likely be faster beyond lists of a few dozen elements.

Comment: I tried this method 

public void setExits(final List<CoordinateBE> exits) {
  if (exits.stream().anyMatch(this.exits::contains)) {
    return;
  }
  this.exits.addAll(exits);
}

Comment: But it is not working properly. I created a unit test, and I received: 

java.lang.AssertionError: [The entrances are the expected ones] 
Expecting:
 <"23.0,24.0, 21.0,22.0, 23.0,24.0, 23.0,24.0">
to be equal to:
 <"23.0,24.0, 21.0,22.0">
ignoring case considerations